# how Channel.isActive() works in netty?

Tags: sockets, tcp, netty, wireshark

I'm using netty 4.x, and I finally find it calls

```
public boolean isActive() {
    SocketChannel ch = javaChannel();
    return ch.isOpen() && ch.isConnected();
}
```

can I use it to check whether the connection between client and server is readable/writeable?

If the answer is yes, then I believe isActive use sth. like heartbeat to check the status of the client. but when I grab the tcp packets I can't find any packets work as heartbeat through wireshark filter tcp.port==12093(it's my server port).

any suggestion is helps.

Comment: isActive tells you whether the socket is open and connected. As you just saw in the code...

Comment: You've better to ask how ```SocketChannel``` isActive works

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Channel.isActive() works by looking up the querying the underlying socket to see if it is connected.

So if we want to know how it works we should dig a little deeper, if you are using netty with tcp connections, you are almost sure you are using the java [nio sockets](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SocketChannel.html).

From io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel:

> ```
> @Override
> public boolean isActive() {
>     SocketChannel ch = javaChannel();
>     return ch.isOpen() && ch.isConnected();
> }
> ```

Both of the above methods aren't that interesting, and are simply boolean flags set to the correct value by native code.

However, since isActive() just returns those boolean flags, you cannot be sure that the connection is still working at the moment you call the function, the best way would be to change your protocol to include some kind of ping message, for example IRC has a ping command, or FTP has the NOOB command.

When sending a ping message, you must make sure that it leaves enough headroom for partial network dropout, for example if your computer is connected through WIFI, there will be some packet loss. However, the native tcp layer in the operating system should handle these packet loss combined with resending for you, but it may mean that after you send a ping message, it may take up to a full minute before isActive() will return false.

If you want to add automatic ping messages to your protocol, it may be wise to look into the [IdleStateHandler](http://netty.io/4.0/api/index.html?io/netty/handler/timeout/IdleStateHandler.html) and the [WriteTimeoutHandler](http://netty.io/4.0/api/index.html?io/netty/handler/timeout/WriteTimeoutHandler.html).

Comment: exactly what I want! I'm now a bit interest about how native code set open & connected flags. how can I check it out?

Comment: @user3754786 You are able to use the java debugger to set a breakpoint on the boolean flags, if those breakpoints are triggered, you can follow the stacktrace even more back (I used a debugger to get to those boolean flags)